# org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory cannot be cast to org.hibernate.cache.RegionFactory

Tags: hibernate

trying to use hibernate with my web app and getting following exception:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not
instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory]
org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory  
[org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory]
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:423)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory cannot be cast to 
org.hibernate.cache.RegionFactory
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:409)
... 31 more
```

Any ides how to resolve this?

Comment: find the problem.  Problem tied to PL/SQL problem in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was a local database issue. problem resolved.