# java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory cannot be cast to org.hibernate.cache.RegionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache, classcastexception

I am trying to configure Ehcache (2.6.0) as Hibernate (3.6.4) second level cache.
I have set the following properties in the spring context file

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
```

When I start the application, it fails with the exception:`java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory cannot be cast to org.hibernate.cache.RegionFactory`

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory cannot be cast to org.hibernate.cache.RegionFactory
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:409)
```

I have looked at the source and observed that  `SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory extends AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory` and `AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory implements RegionFactory`

The code at SettingsFactory.java:409 is

```
            return (RegionFactory) ReflectHelper.classForName( regionFactoryClassName )
                    .getConstructor( Properties.class )
                    .newInstance( properties );
```

Everything seems to be in place but I still get the exception. Any clues ?

Comment: Check the versions of both the jars in your classpath. It might help you.

Comment: Someone [had this very problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897115/org-hibernate-cache-ehcache-singletonehcacheregionfactory-cannot-be-cast-to-org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try by providing Provider Class:

org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider

And also make sure that you have added required jar for ehCache.